# In R, How to split a datset into columns based on variable start/stop positions?

Tags: r, function, substr

I would like to split rows of a dataset based on many pairs of start/stop positions within the row

I can do this with the command `substr` for each one in longhand fashion but this seems like a poor choice.

I actually have 7 datasets for which I need to do this, I am hoping there is a way of defining an array/vector with the start/stop pairs and then feed this to the `substr` command.

Any help guidance would be awesome

```
# I have a datset which contains records like this

string1 <- "08103128827DP        11        513452                  131 Markett Hills Rd Coolingford XYZ 9876                                       14602012476          000000000000000000010784Y00000000000053815"
string2 <- "08203143982DP        12        611218                  12 Magicra Waters Rd Huntley XXX 9081                                           14602012476          000000000000000000010784Y00000000000038443"

# Make a dummy datset
V1 <- c(string1, string2)
myData <- data.frame(V1)
head(myData)

# I would like to split into distinct fields for each row of the typically large dataset that I have
fld_1 <- substr(myData, 0, 3)
fld_2 <- substr(myData, 4, 11)
fld_3 <- substr(myData, 12, 16)
fld_4 <- as.numeric(substr(myData, 187, 198))/100

# The field widths vary, as do the data types
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have exact starting and ending positions:

```
# (0) Make a dummy dataset
string1 <- "08103128827DP        11        513452                  131 Markett Hills Rd Coolingford XYZ 9876                                       14602012476          000000000000000000010784Y00000000000053815"
string2 <- "08203143982DP        12        611218                  12 Magicra Waters Rd Huntley XXX 9081                                           14602012476          000000000000000000010784Y00000000000038443"
V1 <- c(string1, string2)

# (1) Define positions and variable names
pos <- list("Var 1" = c(0, 13),
            "Var 2" = c(22, 23),
            "Var 3" = c(32, 37))

# (2) Extract variables as text
vars <- lapply(pos, function(x) {
  substr(V1, x[1], x[2])
})

# (3) Assign classes
class(vars[["Var 2"]]) <- "numeric"
class(vars[["Var 3"]]) <- "numeric"
```

Comment: Thanks `Dzimitry M.` this is absolutely brilliant.
I have updated my code and it worked like a charm.
I truly appreciate people on this forum taking their time to help people like me.

Answer (score 1):

The fields appear to be separated by 2 or more spaces whereas single spaces are within fields so replace any run of 2 or more spaces with tab and then read it in with a tab separator:

```
read.delim(text = gsub("  +", "\t", as.character(myData$V1)), 
  as.is = TRUE, header = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thaks for your comment, the files are not tab delimited, it just happened that in the sample data it had positions in the data file which had consecutive spaces.

I have the answer from Dzimitry and it worked beautifully

Comment: The files are NOT assumed to be tab delimited in the answer.  They are assumed to have multiple spaces between fields and only single spaces within fields.